# Prove monotone convergence theorem when $\int |f_1| d\mu < \infty$ holds

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

This question is from 3.A exercise 20 from Axler's MIRA book.

Suppose $(X,S,\mu)$ is a measure space and $f_1, f_2, \dots$ is a monotone sequence of $S$-measurable functions. Define $f: X \to [-\infty,\infty]$ by $$f(x) = \lim_{k\to\infty}\{f_k(x)\}.$$ Prove that if $\int|f_1|d\mu < \infty$, then $$\lim_{k\to\infty} \int\{f_k(x)\}d\mu = \int fd\mu. $$

The part that I don't understand how to use the assumption $\int |f_1| < \infty$. For example if we assumed that $\int |f_1| = \infty$, then I guess a counter example could be found to show why the equality won't hold? I don't think I am thinking correctly about this problem at all and my intuition is all off.

Comment: Is your $\langle f_n\rangle$ monotonically *decreasing*?

Comment: it can be either monotone increasing or monotone decreasing

Comment: I also wonder about your statement on the problem is correct, because the monotone convergence theorem is usually about monotone sequences of *non-negative* measurable functions, not for arbitrary ones.

Comment: its problem 20 on page 87 of section 3A of Axler's book "Measure, Integration, and Real Analysis"

Answer (score 1):

The assumption $\int |f_1|d\mu<\infty$ is necessary for some cases, e.g., when your sequence is *decreasing and non-negative*. For example, consider $f_n=\chi_{[n,\infty)}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual Lebesgue measure. Then $\int_\mathbb{R} f_nd\mu=\infty$, but $\lim f_n=0$, so the statement does not hold.

You may follow the hint below to solve your problem:

> If you know the monotone convergence theorem for *non-negative* functions, you may try to decompose functions into non-negative parts and non-positive parts.